# Using valgrind's massif with argument parameters for an application

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks, valgrind, mtrace

I have a code executable as "demonstrate"> I want to have a neat memory profiling for thios executable. I have gone through the valgrind's massif tool and found out to be something which could fetch me results that I am looking for. Although there is a slight issues I am coming across.

My executable takes various arguments and w/o it it wont run e.g ./demonstrate -t 10 -p 1 -P 3

As soon as I run massif on the above statement it tells me 
"Error allocating heap"

```
taskset -c 0-10 valgrind --tool=massif  ./demonstrate -t 10 -p 1 -P 3
==4140== Massif, a heap profiler
==4140== Copyright (C) 2003-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote
==4140== Using Valgrind-3.6.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4140== Command: ./demonstrate -t 10
==4140==
Error allocating heap
==4140==
```

Quite similar issue happened with mtrace. Included mcheck header and called mtrace and muntrace at the beginning and end and tried calling demonstrate
e.g

```
mtrace ./demonstrate -t 10 -p 1 -P 3 -f file.txt mALLOCoUT.TXT

Wrong number of arguments, run /usr/bin/mtrace --help for help. at /usr/bin/mtrace   line    89.
```

Although when I run the application without the valgrind option the application runs fine:

```
./demonstrate -t 10 -p 1 -P 3
Opened 1
Opened 2
Opened 3
Allocated huge page size=1073741824
Pushed 262144 pages
```

Any suggestion on how to get any of these working with several command line arguments.

Comment: maybe some of arguments to the other executable match arguments of massif, and massif mistakes them for their own. Try with a '--' (no quotes) before the executable name (space after).

Comment: doesnt seem to work with --. Trying to write a separate function based on : http://virtualthreads.blogspot.ca/2006/02/understanding-memory-usage-on-linux.html

Comment: You're allocating 256k 1M pages, or 256Tb? The Valgrind defaults won't work with that amount of memory. If you really have that much then you'll need to modify Valgrind so that it puts its own memory out of the way. Also you are using mtrace incorrectly. As I understand it you need to modify your exe to use the mtrace function, run your exe and then use the script mtrace to process the generated log.